# How can I configure one of the ubuntu desktops as "dhcp-relay-agent"?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, iptables

How can I relay DHCP requests from LAN to WAN in linux so that the desktop connected to the LAN interface can have Internet access from WAN?

Note: WAN has Internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me ...

Installed three packages: iproute2, bcrelay, and parprouted. After that, I typed the following.

```
bcrelay -i ethx -o wlanx
parprouted -d -p wlanx ethx
```

Where "ethx" is your LAN interface and "wlanx" is wireless. I had tried this quite a long back so not sure about the position of the interfaces in syntax. Please check the man pages for reference.